# Keyframes not visible on timeline when selecting a bone in Pose Mode? -- v2.83.1

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, keyframes, timeline

Every time I select a bone in Pose Mode, none of my keyframes show up but my animation still plays. So far I've tried changing/clicking in the "View" menu of the "Timeline" editor...

- Disabling/enabling "Only Keyframes from Selected Channels" -- When disabled it only shows my shape keys.
- Disabled "Only Show Errors"
- Hit "Frame All" multiple times (which is "View All" in my case.)
- Hit "Go to Current Frame"

I've also tried in the "Timeline" editor...

- Scrubbing up and down holding down middle click
- Zooming in/out of my timeline
- Checking "Summary" but below it shows nothing

The only time Blender will show my keyframes is when I go to my Hair Bones Layer with it's baked Wiggle Addon data and my Shape Keys. Bones that control the head, fingers, hands/etc do not have their keyframes visible no matter what I try. Before all of this happened, I was able to see all my keyframes until I had enabled an addon known as "Wiggle Bones" and baked it onto my hair.

Screenshot: [image]

My goal is to have my keyframes visible again for bones such as the one which controls the head. Any help? :, D

Comment: maybe you've pushed your action in the NLA? If it's not the case, please share your file (at least the armature): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: What do you mean by I "pushed my action in the NLA?"

Comment: Also, heres my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sWkqhqga5xi6QvSWXd0CgglJ0VIoHog2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in the file you made available for downloading.

Comment: Oof well it's okay now since someone already found the answer to my issue so no worries  ovo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see if you open the *NonLiner Animation* window, you've pushed your action into it (the yellow strip we see). Now open the *Dope Sheet* window, switch it to *Action Editor* mode. You can either select the yellow strip, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to bring back the action, or select it in the dropdown menu.

[image]

Remember that if you press on the *Dope Sheet Push Down* button the action will play in the *NLA* but it won't be available in the *Dope Sheet* anymore, this is what probably happened here.

Comment: Oh I understand now

Comment: Thank you! This actually fixed my issue, I'm able to edit/see the keyframes again!! :D